Verifying kernel images in Grub2 using certificates stored in UEFI DB
Question: Is there no way to use the certificates stored in the UEFI firmware to verify the kernel images in GRUB2 (without shim)? If so, is there a technical reason why this cannot work, or nobody needed it and therefore it was not implemented?
Background: I am working on an embedded project where I need to implement secure boot using the GRUB2 bootloader. Since I use yocto to build the firmware images, I looked at the meta-secure-core layer to find out how to verify my images. The boot process using this layer seems to be UEFI->shim->SELoader->GRUB->kernel.
I feel that the boot process using a shim and SELoader is overly complicated. I do have full control over the UEFI bios and can install my own certificates. So what I would like to do is just UEFI->GRUB->kernel. I know that I could load the kernel directly with UEFI-Stub, but I do need a small boot-script in GRUB with the logic for my A/B update system.
What I have accomplished so far is installing my own keys in UEFI and building a signed grub image that can be verified and loaded by the UEFI firmware. Now I want to load the signed kernel. The only documentation I can find about kernel verification in GRUB2 (without a shim) is how to verify the kernel using PGP. But this means that I need to manage an additional set of keys for kernel signing next to the keys needed to sign the bootloader. I would rather have only one set of keys.
Edit 2024-11-04:
Some additional information about what I tried: I've built the grub binary using the grub-mkimage tool using the following command:
grub-mkimage -v --disable-shim-lock 
     -c ${WORKDIR}/grub-recovery.cfg 
     -m ${S}/memdisk.tar
     -p /EFI/BOOT 
     -d ${WORKDIR}/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/ 
     -O x86_64-efi 
     -o ${S}/grub-x86_64.efi 
     boot linux fat part_gpt normal loadenv memdisk tar configfile test crypto gcry_sha256 gcry_sha512 gcry_dsa gcry_rsa pgp password_pbkdf2

Some comments about the parameters

disable-shim-lock is used because I do not use the shim binary
the grub-recovery.cfg is the grub script that is run when grub starts. It consists of only one line: configfile (memdisk)/grub.cfg This is done because grub-recover.cfg runs in the grub rescue mode where only a subset of the commands are available. Moving the code from the grub.cfg file into grub-recovery.cfg did not work and caused all kinds of errors because of unknown commands etc.
The memdisk.tar contains the actual grub.cfg script to run. This script loads the linux kernel using the linux command.

The resulting grub binary was then signed with my own DB key (which is configured in the UEFI secure boot settings) using the sbsignutility.  This allows the UEFI bios to correctly load the GRUB bootloader without any error.
I also signed the kernel binary with the same key as the GRUB binary. When I try to load the kernel from within the grub.cfg script using the linux command, the GRUB bootloader displayes the follwing error and falls back to the rescue cli:
error: verification requested but nobody cares: /EFI/BOOT/mykernel

So I guess that there is something missing in my GRUB which actually verifies the kernel image. I would expect that the missing piece is a module that I did not include in my GRUB image which uses the UEFI secure boot certificates to verify the kernel image. But I cannot find any documentation about what module that would be.
Edit 2024-11-05:
I could not figure out how to make GRUB use the keys configured in the UEFI secure boot section. In the meantime I've opted to use the gpg validation module offered by GRUB.

If I've understood correctly, the UEFI firmware always does the certificate checking for anything that looks like an UEFI PE binary file (i.e. grubx64.efi and the kernel with the UEFI stub), and the shim just provides a way to add more certificates to the checking process. GRUB uses firmware services to load the kernel in memory, and with Secure Boot, the firmware just tells the CPU to mark the memory range it loaded a file into as non-executable unless the loaded data looks like a PE binary with a valid signature.

Sure, with your own keys, nothing stops you from building a version of GRUB that undoes the non-executable memory protection... but if you then wanted to distribute that, you should not be able to get that signed by any competent well-known Secure Boot CA, and it would eventually get on the Secure Boot blacklist as a "Secure Boot circumvention device" on any systems that use uefi.org Secure Boot revocation lists.

@telcoM: It does not seem to be the case that the UEFI firmware is checking the certificate in this case. I use the command 'linux /EFI/BOOT/mykernel' to load the kernel image in the GRUB script. If secure boot is enabled (and therefore, check_signatures is set), GRUB shows me an error message when I try to load the kernel: "error: verification requested but nobody cares: /EFI/BOOT/mykernel"

D*mn. Looking at the source code, GRUB registers a shim_lock verifier when Secure Boot is in effect, and expects to use it. With no shim present, that obviously cannot succeed. But apparently you can build GRUB with --disable-shim-lock build-time option to avoid that piece of code.
